# actionscript reading large xlsx file

Tags: xml, excel, actionscript, air

I am working on a project based on adobe air which reads entries from excel file with xlsx extension and then use it in some purpose. and i am using this lib to read the file https://github.com/childoftv/as3-xlsx-reader. it is working great but the problem is the excel file has like 300000 rows which makes the application run extremely slow when looping reading entries.
i thought about putting the entries first in xml format but i found that it takes only 20000 entries in the xml.
so i am asking if there is any other way to read the file? or is there a solution to that 20000 xml entry thing?
thanks and sorry for the long question

Comment: Not sure how this will apply to your xlsx reader code, but it is always faster to Excel data into arrays and work with the array than it is to access via Excel Ranges. Chip Pearson has an [excellent discussion](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: yeah that is why i am trying to put data in xml which is faster to read